# PDO Update not updating db

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I can't get this code to update my, mysql database.

```
        $SQL = $odb -> prepare("UPDATE `LB` SET `running` = `running` + 1 WHERE `url`= :url");
        $SQL -> execute(array(":url"=> $url ));
```

May someone please help, I have searched for this and couldn't find something like this.

Comment: Searched for what? I am curious, what did you search for?

Comment: PDO does not update your DB. it just runs a query against database. so, either it just cannot find a record to update or there is an error while running a query. So, you have to check your data for the former and search for the "how to know if PDO raised an error" for the latter

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't do :url in your array, there is no need for it.

You can also use a question mark in place of your =:url like so:

```
url=?
```

Then in your array, you can either place a direct value:

```
$SQL->execute(array($url));
```

Or you can bind values incrementally:

```
$SQL->bindValue(1, $url, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$SQL->execute();
```

Except, instead of using PDO::PARAM_INT, you would use your own parameters...

So I'm guessing in your instance you would use PDO::PARAM_STR

Hopefully this helps :)

Comment: Apparently what wont @YourCommonSense ?